# adobe flash not working?

Tags: flash, chromium

hi friends i am having a problem whenever i try to play videos on you tube or any other site i always get an error

```
adobe flash player is required to display some contents on this page
```

but the problem is that i already have adobe flash plugin i downloaded it from software center .

but still it does not works can someone please help me

and when i tried downloading for ubuntu from adobe site it opened software center and a message was there:

```
There isn’t a software package called “adobe-flashplugin” in your current software sources
```

Comment: Did you enable a 'partner' repository?

Comment: how to do that i dont hink so i did

Comment: Run `sudo software-properties-gtk`, select "Other Software" tab, tick "Canonical Partners", run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: i did that but when i closed other software it asked to update cache so its doing that now .its downloading some packages

Answer (score 1):

Chromium uses a google flash plugin called "Pepper".  The package you need to install is called pepperflashplugin-nonfree -- frustrated the pajeebus outta me.